# php email sanitize and validation not working

Tags: php, email-validation, phone-number, filter-var

I have this php code

```
if(filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) !== false && filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
                echo 'it is mail';
            }else{
                echo 'is is phone';
            }
```

when I'm sending the post data like this

```
example@bla.com
```

it is writing it is mail. but when I'm sending the data like this

```
+995216846121
```

then it is writing also that it is mail

what is wrong?
please help me.

I need to check if client add mail or phone number.

Comment: filter_validate_email properly rejects the phone number here. try debugging your system: do a `var_dump(filter_var(...))` for BOTH of those options, and confirm that they're returning the proper true/false.

Comment: now I try var_dump(filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL));
and in the both of them it returns string(here length) and the same string
something is wrong 
can I convert this string in inteher like (int)$_POST['username'] and then check it ?
or something like this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have an error in this code. For me it's working fine

Comment: yes I`m sure. it is not working.
I give you my code how I`m checking.
and it is not working.

Comment: sanitize just cleans up and returns whatever's left of the string. validate returns a true/false...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added one more check with is_numeric() and now everithing is good.
thenk you All!!!

Comment: Another option would be regex. Then you can define own patterns for email and phone.

Comment: no regex not need.
is_numeric class is doing what I needed.
So if I send data e.g. +124654654
it will returns me true;

Comment: I wrote `Another option`, not `the one and only` ;)
If you can ensure that phone numers always have this format your solution is fine. But if someone would enter "+12 123123-34" is_numberic would return `false` because of the space and the "-".

Comment: So can you give me the regex code with removing minus,space and other characters what can user use

in this case may be user add +(995) 5(58) 55-55-55
or I do not know.
can you give me this regex?
So I`ll be sure that user not will write anything more.

Comment: I would just do an str_replace for anything <>[0-9], for the beginning.